# No such method after upgrade to Grails 2.4.1

Tags: grails

I just upgraded to `Grails 2.4.1` and it seems that there is a problem with `tag libraries`.

```
Class java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
Message org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.getOut(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/Writer;
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <asset:javascript>: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.getOut(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/Writer;
... 8 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <asset:javascript>: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.getOut(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/Writer;
at home_saw303_dev_projects_zsc_supporter_grails_app_views_layouts_zscsupporter_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(home_saw303_dev_projects_zsc_supporter_grails_app_views_layouts_zscsupporter_gsp:36)
at home_saw303_dev_projects_zsc_supporter_grails_app_views_layouts_zscsupporter_gsp.run(home_saw303_dev_projects_zsc_supporter_grails_app_views_layouts_zscsupporter_gsp:43)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.getOut(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/Writer;
at asset.pipeline.AssetsTagLib$_closure1_closure10.doCall(AssetsTagLib.groovy:45)
at asset.pipeline.AssetsTagLib$_closure1.doCall(AssetsTagLib.groovy:43)
... 10 more
```

Can you confirm this behaviour? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you describe what it takes to reproduce the problem in a new 2.4.1 app?  I can’t tell for sure by looking at your stack trace but it looks like there may be something relevant in your zscsupporter layout.

Comment: Well that is strange. I tried to reproduce in a plain new Grails 2.4.1 app. After `grails create-app` and `grails run-app` Grails downloaded additional dependencies which it did not download when I upgraded the zscsupporter app. After that the problem disappeared. How do I upgrade Grails 2.4.x apps in general? What is the correct workflow? All I did what `grails set-grails-version 2.4.1` but this did not seem to force grails download the dependencies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think a `grails clean` in your original app after upgrading will make the problem go away.  The issue is that you have a GSP which was compiled with an earlier version of Grails and that compiled class is not compatible with the version of Grails you are using now.